# Count the number of times a string appears in a range, whilst a related cell is equal to a specific string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The goal of this task is to understand which fields of specialism (Front End, Back End, Full Stack, N/A) within an organisation, what technologies do each engineer know?

I.E "Oh look, across our Engineering team, 35 out of 75 FE Engineers know Python, and 42 out of 45 BE Engineers know Java"

Therefore, I have 2 sheets of data.

Sheet 1 contains a list of all software engineers in a business, the technologies that they know, and the engineer's specialism (Front End, Back End, Full Stack, N/A).

Sheet 2 contains a filtered/sanitized list of technologies, and the count for the engineers that have noted that down as a technology that they know/have some experience with, and is where I'm trying to bring this final piece of data in.

I'm 99% the way there already, but I just can't figure out how to limit the count based off of their specialism.

| Name | Stack | Tech |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Full Stack | ruby, scss, python |
| John | Front End | rust, c++, nodejs |
| Barry | Back End | flutter, c++, scss |
| Dave | N/A | ruby, erlang, scss |

I now have managed to sanitize that data down to the next 4 tables. Note - Quantity *currently* is just a simple count of the number of engineers that have written down this particular technology and is not filtered by stack preference (see attached photo also).

| FE Technology | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Rust | 2 |
| Flutter | 5 |
| Ruby | 2 |
| SCSS | 8 |

| BE Technology | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Rust | 2 |
| Flutter | 5 |
| Ruby | 2 |
| SCSS | 8 |

| FS Technology | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Rust | 2 |
| Flutter | 5 |
| Ruby | 2 |
| SCSS | 8 |

| N/A Technology | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Rust | 2 |
| Flutter | 5 |
| Ruby | 2 |
| SCSS | 8 |

[image]

**What I need is for the quantity columns (E, H, K, N) to only be specific to the engineer's stack (Front End, Back End, Full Stack, N/A).**

The formula (or script) should refer to the cell next to the quantity for the name of the technology, but also only include if the engineer's stack preference is 'Front End' for example.

In summary something like: Count number of engineers with 'front end' as their specialism where technology is equal to 'terraform' (or 'ansible' or 'bash' etc etc etc).

The App Script & formula I have used to get a list of sanitized data (excludes duplicates and excludes 'banned words' that were entered that don't relate to a technology name) is:

`=unique(filter(AllTechnologies('Form Responses 1'!O2:O275), NOT(COUNTIF(R2:R, AllTechnologies('Form Responses 1'!O2:O275)))))`

Where 'AllTechnologies' is:

```
function AllTechnologies(input) {
  var input = input.toString();
  var inputSplit = input.split(" ");
  Logger.log(inputSplit);
  inputSplit = inputSplit.toString();

  var punctuationless = inputSplit.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\?^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g," ");
  var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
  finalString = finalString.toLowerCase();
  return finalString.split(" ");
}
```

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If `Sheet1` had this table,

| Name | Stack | Tech |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Full Stack | ruby, scss, python |
| John | Front End | rust, c++, nodejs |
| Barry | Back End | flutter, c++, scss |
| Dave | N/A | ruby, erlang, scss |

In `Sheet2`

A1: Datavalidation: `=Sheet1!B2:B`

A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UNIQUE(FLATTEN(SPLIT(Sheet1!C2:C6,", ",1,1)))},"Where Col1 is not null"))
```

This creates a unique list of all languages after splitting by `,`

B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!C$2:C$5), ".*\Q"&A2:A9&"\E.*")*(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!B$2:B$5)=A1),1,0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(Sheet1!C$2:C$5))^0))
```

This creates the count based on DV in A1

| Front End | count |
| --- | --- |
| ruby | 0 |
| scss | 0 |
| python | 0 |
| rust | 1 |
| c++ | 1 |
| nodejs | 1 |
| flutter | 0 |
| erlang | 0 |

Comment: Hey @TheMaster, Thanks for your answer.

When I try the data validation expression: "=Sheet1!B2:B", I get the following error: "An array value could not be found." despite my data and name of sheets matching the exact same format as yours

Comment: @JamieBohanna It's a [datavalidation rule: List from a range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103)